# why does cv2.ocl.haveOpenCL() return false

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, opencl

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXUcV.png)

My graphics card is NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti. It ought to support OpenCL I think

Comment: welcome. please take the [tour] and review [ask]. if your screenshot contains any information you think is important, copy it as text into your question. -- remove that "opencv" package. it's outdated and not original (it's from anaconda/conda/conda-forge, or even worse). use `pip3 install opencv-python`, which is the official package.

Comment: sorry, I am new here so maybe I have broken some rules. Thank you very much for answering my question.

Comment: to "answer" the question (I still don't know if the weird package is to blame), yes, `haveOpenCL()` should return true in all cases. it should even return true if there's only a CPU, because OpenCL can run on CPUs. if it doesn't return true, that might be due to a faulty build. those unofficial builds have unknown quality. they might have been built without any OpenCL support. the official package works just fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.